# keyboard pushes content upwards with ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to ionic and i am designing a login page. However i noticed when i deploy the app to an ios device, the native ios keyboard pushes the content upwards when a input field is clicked/pressed on.

I have been trying to figure out how to solve this issue, but i have had no luck. I am currently using the latest ionic framework.

Is there a way where i can ensure content is not pushed up?

here is my login html:

```
<ion-content class="background" [fullscreen]="true" slot="fixed">
  <h1 class="login-title-text">ign you in</h1>
  <p class="login-subtitle-text">Welcome back!</p>

  <div class="inputs">
    <ion-input class="item-input" type="email" placeholder="Email"></ion-input>
    <ion-input class="item-input" type="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
  </div>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-button color="dark" expand="block">Login</ion-button>
  <ion-button color="dark" expand="block">Forgot Password</ion-button>
  <ion-button color="dark" expand="block">Register</ion-button>
</ion-footer>
```

Here is my scss:

```
ion-content {
    --keyboard-offset: 0px;
  }
  
.background {
    --background: url("/assets/img/background.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
}

.login-title-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 50px 0 20px 30px;
}

.login-subtitle-text {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 0 20px 30px;
}

.inputs {
    padding: 30px;
}

.item-input {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    text-indent: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ion-footer {
    padding: 30px;

    ion-button {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is default behavior of OS. if you content not get pushed upside how user will click on next input?

Comment: okay that makes sense - but what happens if i have a screen that has a list in it, when the search bar is clicked and keyboard displays, obviously the whole list wont be pushed up - the keyboard should overlap the content and not push it up, if that makes sense

Comment: then check your css. you might be using some kind of CSS to pushing content upside. Can you make stackblitz for this issue.

Comment: content pushing works only when your input is in lower part of your screen i.e in place of keyboard then OS pushes your content upside for users to see. but if your search bar in upper part of screen keyboard will overlap the content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally fixed this issue. I installed the capacitor keyboard package.

```
npm install @capacitor/keyboard
```

then navigated to root dir project where the package.json is and ran this command:

```
npx cap sync
```

added this in capacitor.config.ts inside the CapacitorConfig object

```
  plugins: {
    Keyboard: {
      resize: KeyboardResize.None,
    },
  },
```

then I ran

```
npm install
```

might be best to restart simulators after you have done this.

Comment: I also got the same problem. This solution worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the keyboard package into your `.ts` file

`import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx';`

Then you need to add an event to your input element

`(onShown)="hideKey()"` <-- it depend on the input element, this eg., is taken from calendar control onShow

Below is the code to hide the keyboard

```
hideKey() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.keyboard.hide();
    }, 500);
  }
```

I hope this solution will help you

Thanks.

Comment: do i use npm to install ionic-native/keyboard/ngx ?

Comment: yes pls follow this link`https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/keyboard`

Comment: this does not work - i am using a click event (click)="hideKey()" in the html. the same default behaviour of the screen sliding up is still present.